# JavaFX - Best way to load new content

Tags: performance, javafx, preload

i have a small JavaFX application. You can see the structure below.

[image]

The root-element is a AnchorPane (probably this a wrong approach). It contains four AnchorPanes. The orange AnchorPane containts a navigation. The green AnchorPane contains a table, which only changes when a new site is selected. The yellow AnchorPane contains a title and five buttons, which changes the content of the blue AnchorPane.

At the moment i'm deleting the whole blue AnchorPane from the root AnchorPane and loading a new one into it. But this takes some time. What is the best way, to load (fast) a new AnchorPane into the blue Box?

The five possible contents of the blue AnchorPanes are all forms.

Should i recap all AnchorPanes to one View and reload the whole Content?

**Sorry, my english isn't that good. Thank you in advance.**

[image]

EDIT:

```
URL newContent = getClass().getResource(newView);
Main.root.getChildren().remove(3);
AnchorPane anchorPane = FXMLLoader.load(newContent);
anchorPane.setLayoutX(965);
anchorPane.setLayoutY(30);
Main.root.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
```

that's how i add it.

Comment: How do you load the blue area that it takes such a long time? It does not look like a too complex layout, let alone one that would take a long time to be layouted. (I assume in the screenshot the `Testing` part including the tools in the center corresponds to the yellow part in your sketch of the structure.)

Comment: I remove the 3. child from the root and loading with the FXMLLoader a new FXML-AnchorPane. Unfortunatly i left the code at work.

Comment: and yes they do. I dont know how to structure this ...